# How to display a pop-up when users clicks on existing links in the page?

Tags: javascript, popup, google-tag-manager

I'd like to fire a popup to users that click on a link (it can be the menu or the footer, etc.). I plan to use Google Tag Manager to set-up this popup. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: not much to go on... you need to post code that you've already tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "post code"?

Comment: I mean you have to include the code you have already tried and could not get working.